# How can I check if a View is visible (android listview)

Tags: android, listview, view, visible

I've created a library that allows user to download images in background and put it in a View,  passed by argument to a function, when download is finished. The problem is that if I use my library in a listview, calling this method in the getView() method, when a user scroll very fast, the library do a request for each row passed. But I'd like to do it, only when a cell is really visible by user... maybe when the scroll list is stopped. So, how can I check this thing on the single view that I pass to the library method? 
Thaaanks

Comment: if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)

Comment: @AkarshM so with a fast scroll will not be View.VISIBLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

1. **[getVisibility ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility())** Returns the visibility status for this view .
2. **[isShown ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29)** Returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors .

### getVisibility()

```
 if (ViewObj.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    // Your Staff
} else {
   // Your Staff
}
```

### isShown ()

> True if this view and all of its ancestors are VISIBLE

Comment: Ah ok....but What do you mean with visible? With a fast scroll the view will be View.VISIBLE or not ?

Comment: its not offScreen or OnScreen, right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `view.getVisibility()`. The result will be `View.VISIBLE`, `View.GONE`or `View.INVISIBLE`.

If you want to do something when your view is visible, then your expected result will be: `View.VISIBLE`

```
if(yourView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
//Do what you want..
}
```